# How do you get permission to drop files in your wsl2 instance from Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, wsl2

How do you get permission to drop files in your wsl2 instance from Windows?

`\\\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04`

I tried to drop it in there, but I keep getting: "You need permission to perform this action."

I want to drop some files on my C drive to my WSL folder so I can access it from WSL without suffering a performance penalty when I try to run Docker from WSL from a folder that's in my C drive (Windows file system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen this documented (could be wrong), but in a quick test it appears to me that  WSL prohibits access to any root-owned file or directory through the `\\wsl$\<distro>` share.

Some options:

- Navigate to `\\\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\your_username` and drop the files there
- Create a directory under root `/` and `chown` to your user:

  ```
  cd /
  sudo mkdir project
  sudo chown $USER:$USER project
  ```

  You should be able to drop into that folder as well.

Alternatively, you can move the files from the command-line using the `/mnt/c` mount.  For example:

```
cd ~
mv /mnt/c/Users/youruser/Documents/project/myproject .
```